# change redirection of Sign Up button Web2py

Tags: web2py

I tried to create a page registrer.html in default/user/
with this following function in my controler but the redirection doesn't work.

```
def register():
    form = auth.register(next=auth.settings.register_next)
    return dict(form = form)
```

Where is it possible to change the settings of this drop down menu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post-login redirection in web2py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359263/post-login-redirection-in-web2py)

Comment: I reformulated my post

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking? What drop down menu are you talking about, and what does that have to do with the redirection?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll try to explain more clearly what I want. In the layout  we have access to a menu on the top right of every page where a new user can register or a user can log in. I would like to customize these, for example I would like my register form to have some of the fields to be hidden unless a box is checked. This is why I thought I would make my own register.html and wanted to redirect to this page when clicking on the register button in this menu. I don't know if it's the best method but if it is possible I would like to know how. (and also know how to rename these buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `next` parameter indicates where to redirect the user *after* a successful registration. If you want to provide your own controller and view for the register form, then you could use:

```
def user():
    if request.args(0) == "register":
        # Use my own view.
        response.view = "views/default/your-custom-tempalte.html"
        form = auth.register(...)
        return dict(form=form)
    else:
        # Provide the default view for the remaining actions (log in, log out, etc.)
        return dict(form=auth())
```

Although web2py's philosophy is "convention over configuration" and "everything should have a default", that doesn't mean you *must* use the defaults. Usually even the defaults in web2py are very customizable. However the `auth.navbar()` function, which builds the "user" navigation bar, is not highly customizable.

In short: if the defaults are not good enough, just write your own navigation bar.